# integral of anti-symmetric (odd) multi-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is anti-symmetric (odd) in $y$, which means $f(x,-y) = -f(x,y)$

then is it right that the double integral of $f$ over a region that is symmetric is $0$?

more precisely, is it sufficient that the region of integration is symmetric in $y$,

in other words, the region of integration need not be symmetric in $x$,

then the double integral is $0$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will appreciate if somebody can plot an example of such function in 3 dimensional space.

Comment: Yes, if you perform the integral over y first, then at any fixed x, the restricted function is just a normal one dimensional odd function, over a symmetric integration domain, so the inner integral is 0

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to generalize it to $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

$G \in \mathbb R^n$ is symmetric with respect to $x_1 ((x_1, x_2 ...x_n)\in G  \Leftrightarrow (-x_1,x_2, ... x_n)\in G)$ and $f: G\subset \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable in $G$ such that $f(x_1,.., x_n) = -f(-x_1...x_n)$ for all $(x_1,...,x_n)\in G$.

Demonstrating $G$ as $G_1 \times G_2 \times ...\times G_n$.
The function: $h: G_1\rightarrow \mathbb R , h(x_1) = \int _{G_2\times ...\times G_n} f(x_1,x_2...x_n)dx_2...dx_n$ is an odd function because:

$h(x_1) = \int _{G_2\times ...\times G_n} f(x_1,x_2...x_n)dx_2...dx_n = $

$ = \int _{G_2\times ...\times G_n} -f(-x_1,x_2...x_n)dx_2...dx_n = $

$ = -1\int _{G_2\times ...\times G_n} f(-x_1,x_2...x_n)dx_2...dx_n = -1\cdot h(-x_1)$

From here we can use the regular one-dimensional theorem of integration of an odd function over a symmetric domain for $h$ and get that $\int_{G_1} h(x)  dx_1 =0$ which leads to $\int _G f(x_1 ...f_n) dx_1...dx_n = 0$.